# SQL Difference between two row in group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `records` of store id, processing batch id and start time as follows:

```
|store_id | batch_id | process_start_time |
| A       | 1        | 10                 |
| B       | 1        | 40                 |
| C       | 1        | 30                 |
| A       | 2        | 400                |
| B       | 2        | 800                |
| C       | 2        | 600                |
| A       | 3        | 10                 |
| B       | 3        | 80                 |
| C       | 3        | 90                 |
```

Here, rows needed to be grouped by `batch_id` and `time_taken` is *difference* of `process_start_time` of **store A** and **store C**.

So, the expected result would be:

```
batch_id | time_taken
1        | 20
2        | 200
3        | 80
```

I tried to do something like:

```
select batch_id, ((select process_start_time from records where store_id = 'C') - (select process_start_time from records where store_id = 'A')) as time_taken 
from records group by batch_id;
```

But couldn't figure out to select specific rows in that particular group.

Thank you for looking into!

Update: the process_start_time column not necessarily max for store C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want conditional aggregation and arithmetic:

```
select batch_id,
       (max(case when store_id = 'C' then process_start_time end) -
        min(case when store_id = 'A' then process_start_time end)
       ) as diff
from records
group by batch_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a self join.

```
SELECT r1.batch_id,
       r1.process_start_time - r2.process_start_time time_taken
       FROM records r1
            INNER JOIN records r2
                       ON r1.batch_id = r2.batch_id
       WHERE r1.store_id = 'C'
             AND r2.store_id = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank for taking time to look into! seems gives the same result as Gordon has mentioned! just wondering if perf of Gordon's query would be better as no join on there?

Comment: @YogenRai: Compare the plans. Mine might benefit from an index on `(store_id, batch_id)` or maybe even more with one on `(store_id, batch_id, process_start_time)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer. This is using two instances of the records table and we link them up with where clauses and exists as follows:

```sql
select a.batch_id,
       c.process_start_time - a.process_start_time as time_taken
from   records a,
       records c
where  a.store_id = 'A'
and    c.store_id = 'C'
and    exists (
select 1
from   records x
where  x.batch_id = a.batch_id
and    x.batch_id = c.batch_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    store_a.batch_id,
    store_c.process_start_time - store_a.process_start_time AS 'time_taken'
    FROM records store_a  
    INNER JOIN records store_c
    ON store_a.batch_id = store_c.batch_id 
       AND store_c.store_id = 'C' 
       AND  store_a.store_id = 'A'
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide comments (either in-code or before/after) as to why this answer would work? Thanks!